# Django setup with Apache and mod_wsgi on Mac: configuration problems

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to run a local Django server on Apache with mod_wsgi. I am running the out-of-the-box Apache on Mac.

```
hobbes3@hobbes3:~/Sites/mysite$ apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.21 (Unix)
Server built:   Nov 15 2011 15:12:57
```

Apache properly loads mod_wsgi.

```
hobbes3@hobbes3:~/Sites/mysite$ apachectl -M | grep wsgi
Syntax OK
wsgi_module (shared)
```

In my `httpd.conf` file I load `apache_django_wsgi.conf` which is

```
WSGIDaemonProcess django
WSGIProcessGroup django
WSGIPythonHome /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/

Alias /mysite/ "/Users/hobbes3/Sites/mysite/"
<Directory "/Users/hobbes3/Sites/mysite">
Order allow,deny
Options Indexes
Allow from all
IndexOptions FancyIndexing
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias /mysite "/Users/hobbes3/Sites/mysite/apache/django.wsgi"

<Directory "/Users/hobbes3/Sites/mysite/apache">
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

My `django.wsgi` file is

```
import os
import sys

paths = [ '/Users/hobbes3/Sites/mysite',
          '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
]

for path in paths:
    if path not in sys.path:
        sys.path.append(path)

sys.executable = '/usr/local/bin/python'
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I can also restart Apache without any error. But when I try to visit `http://localhost/mysite`, the browser just shows the index of my page. At the bottom of the page, it says `Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.2 PHP/5.3.8 with Suhosin-Patch Server at localhost Port 80`.

Before it used to say something about unable to load MySQLdb, but now it doesn't show any errors. But I still can't see my Django site. Here is the previous error (I truncated the dates and times):

```
mod_wsgi (pid=74739): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/Users/hobbes3/Sites/mysite/apache/django.wsgi'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 272, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 169, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 203, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 59, in technical_500_response
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 151, in get_traceback_html
    return t.render(c)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 123, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 117, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 744, in render
    bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 73, in render_node
    result = node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 90, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 536, in resolve
    new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaultfilters.py", line 695, in date
    return format(value, arg)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 285, in format
    return df.format(format_string)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 30, in format
    pieces.append(force_unicode(getattr(self, piece)()))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 191, in r
    return self.format('D, j M Y H:i:s O')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 30, in format
    pieces.append(force_unicode(getattr(self, piece)()))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 71, in force_unicode
    s = unicode(s)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 206, in __unicode_cast
    return self.__func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 81, in ugettext
    return _trans.ugettext(message)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 286, in ugettext
    return do_translate(message, 'ugettext')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 276, in do_translate
    _default = translation(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 185, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 162, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.helpers import ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/helpers.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.util import (flatten_fieldsets, lookup_field,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/util.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 78, in <module>
    connection = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 93, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 33, in load_backend
    return import_module('.base', backend_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 14, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
TemplateSyntaxError: Caught ImproperlyConfigured while rendering: Error loading MySQLdb module: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.4-x86_64.egg/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.4-x86_64.egg/_mysql.so
```

Comment: Why are you wanting the Alias directive for '/mysite/'? As Daniel points out, it is taking precedence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got both an `Alias` and a `WSGIScriptAlias` for `mysite`. I'd guess that the first Alias is taking precedence, so Apache is serving a directory listing rather than delegating to mod_wsgi.

Comment: Ya that was it, but now I am having that `TemplateSyntaxError: Caught ImproperlyConfigured while rendering: Error loading MySQLdb module: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.4-x86_64.egg/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib` error again...

Thanks for the help nonetheless. Fixing one error at a time :P.